# Inner join to multiple columns and use in INSERT INSTO....SELECT

Tags: oracle, inner-join, multiple-columns

Table `CUST_DAY0_MERGE` has the following columns

```
NEW_CUST_ID
ACTIVE_REF_ID
OLD_REF_ID_1
OLD_REF_ID_2
OLD_REF_ID_3
```

I would like to create an insert statement into table `CUST_REVIEWS`, with the following columns:

```
CUST_REVIEW_ID
RUN_DATE
CUST_ID
CUST_SOURCE_UNIQUE_ID
CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID
```

This insert statement need to inner join query with`CUST_DAY0_MERGE` with the following conditions:

```
CUST_DAY0_MERGE.OLD_REF_ID_1`=`CUST_REVIEWS.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID
CUST_DAY0_MERGE.OLD_REF_ID_2`=`CUST_REVIEWS.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID
CUST_DAY0_MERGE.OLD_REF_ID_3`=`CUST_REVIEWS.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID
```

If above conditions fullfied, a new record will be inserted to `CUST_REVIEWS` with the following conditions:

```
CUST_REVIEWS.CUST_ID`=`CUST_DAY0_MERGE.NEW_CUST_ID
CUST_REVIEWS.CUST_SOURCE_UNIQUE_ID`=`CUST_DAY0_MERGE.NEW_CUST_ID
```

For others columns should remain unchanged as per existing value.

I have a sample statement as per following:

```
INSERT INTO CUST_REVIEWS(CUST_REVIEW_ID,RUN_DATE,CUST_ID,CUST_SOURCE_UNIQUE_ID,CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID)
SELECT CUST_REVIEW_ID,RUN_DATE,CUST_ID,CUST_SOURCE_UNIQUE_ID,CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID
FROM CUST_REVIEWS reviews
INNER JOIN CUST_DAY0_MERGE merge1
ON (reviews.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID = merge1.OLD_REF_ID_1)
INNER JOIN CUST_DAY0_MERGE merge2
ON (reviews.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID = merge2.OLD_REF_ID_2)
INNER JOIN CUST_DAY0_MERGE merge3
ON (reviews.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID = merge3.OLD_REF_ID_3);
```

How can enhance the insert statement by changing `CUST_ID` and `CUST_SOURCE_UNIQUE_ID` with the condition I would like to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If above conditions fullfied, a new record will be inserted to CUST_REVIEWS" -  you mean

"If at least one of above" 
or
"If all of the above" ?

In second case you may use a single join:

```
INNER JOIN CUST_DAY0_MERGE merge
ON (reviews.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID = merge.OLD_REF_ID_1)
AND
(reviews.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID = merge.OLD_REF_ID_2)
AND
(reviews.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID = merge.OLD_REF_ID_3)
```

In first case you may use "OR" but using "UNION" instead is reported as being more optimal:

```
INNER JOIN CUST_DAY0_MERGE merge
    ON (reviews.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID = merge.OLD_REF_ID_1)
    OR
    (reviews.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID = merge.OLD_REF_ID_2)
    OR
    (reviews.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID = merge.OLD_REF_ID_3)
```

vs.

```
       INSERT INTO CUST_REVIEWS(CUST_REVIEW_ID,RUN_DATE,CUST_ID,CUST_SOURCE_UNIQUE_ID,CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID)  

       SELECT CUST_REVIEW_ID,RUN_DATE,merge.NEW_CUST_ID as CUST_ID,merge.NEW_CUST_ID as CUST_SOURCE_UNIQUE_ID,CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID
FROM CUST_REVIEWS reviews
       INNER JOIN CUST_DAY0_MERGE merge
           ON (reviews.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID = merge.OLD_REF_ID_1)

       UNION
       SELECT CUST_REVIEW_ID,RUN_DATE,merge.NEW_CUST_ID as CUST_ID,merge.NEW_CUST_ID as CUST_SOURCE_UNIQUE_ID,CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID
FROM CUST_REVIEWS reviews    
       INNER JOIN CUST_DAY0_MERGE merge
          ON (reviews.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID = merge.OLD_REF_ID_2)

       UNION
       SELECT CUST_REVIEW_ID,RUN_DATE,merge.NEW_CUST_ID as CUST_ID,merge.NEW_CUST_ID as CUST_SOURCE_UNIQUE_ID,CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID
FROM CUST_REVIEWS reviews    
       INNER JOIN CUST_DAY0_MERGE merge
          ON (reviews.CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID = merge.OLD_REF_ID_3)
```

Comment: at least one of above fullfilled

Comment: I understand the portion of using single join. How about  changing `CUST_ID` and `CUST_SOURCE_UNIQUE_ID` in the insert statement with condtion to `CUST_DAY0_MERGE.NEW_CUST_ID`?

Comment: is your select statement actually correct? shouldn't it be this?: `SELECT CUST_REVIEW_ID,RUN_DATE,MERGE.NEW_CUST_ID,MERGE.NEW_CUST_ID,CUST_SOURCE_REF_ID`

Comment: i tested single join with `OR`, how could be the syntax for inner join with `UNION`? i am having syntax error by replace `OR` with `UNION`

Comment: i see, it required 3 query statements but performance is much optimal as compare to `OR`?

Comment: @user2102665 it depends on different factors, but in general it is considered to be more optimal : )

Comment: i will choose `OR`, the actual columns are more than that, using 3 queries make the code lengthy. thanks!

Comment: Just wonder if I can put the whole statement in a function? the procedure will call function for insertion